# Formatting Full name in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In below example, the `middle_name` is optional. Any name without `middle_name` it takes an extra blank space. Please anyone make correction following method.

```
  def name
    "#{first_name} #{middle_name} #{last_name}".titleize
  end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def name
  [first_name, middle_name, last_name].select(&:present?).join(' ').titleize
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this instead

```
def name
  [first_name, middle_name, last_name].reject(&:blank?).join(' ').titleize
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def name    
   "#{first_name} #{middle_name}#{" " if middle_name.present?}#{last_name}".titleize
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This guards and formats: (e.g.) `=> Scott, Michael G`

```rb
def full_name
  return if last_name.blank? && first_name.blank?

  ["#{last_name}, #{first_name}", middle_initial, suffix].select(&:present?).join(' ').titleize
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Contracting the middle names:

```
def formatted_name(full_name)
  parts = full_name.split
  name  = parts.first
  name += " #{parts[1][0,1].upcase}. " if parts.length > 2
  name += " #{parts[2][0,1].upcase}. " if parts.length > 3
  name += parts.last
end

puts formatted_name("Bob Alan Faria Stwart") => "Bob A. F. Stwart"
```